# Override built-in Redis commands with C modules

Tags: api, module, redis

I try to override the `set` Redis built-in command by implementing a module using the Redis API. I would like to publish the set value on a specific channel. `notify-keyspace-events KEAg` would have been a good solution if the value was sent on the channel but it is not the case.

I also tried to override the `set` command directly with the API, but `RedisModule_CreateCommand` seems only work for new commands, not for built-in commands.

I also tried to create a command like `setpub` and use `rename-command SET SETPUB` but `SETPUB doesn't seem to be recognize, even if we use`rename-command`after`loadmodule setpub.so`.

Is there a way to override the built-in commands?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. There will probably soon be a way to wrap native redis commands with hooks, but that's still not available.

But you can use the new module notification API in 4.0.9, and register a notification handler inside your module, and in it extract the value of the key being set - then publish it.

The notification handler should look something likes this (not testing for validity):

```
int NotifyCallback(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, int type, const char *event,
                   RedisModuleString *key) {

  // We only care about SET events, right?
  if (!strcasecmp(event, "SET")) {


     // Open the key to get the string in it. We could have used RedisModule_Call but this is faster:
     RedisModuleKey *k = RedisModule_OpenKey(ctx, key, REDISMODULE_READ);

     // Just to be safe...
     if (k && RedisModule_KeyType(k) == REDISMODULE_KEYTYPE_STRING) {

         // Get direct access to the string. Careful now!
         size_t len;   
         char *str = RedisModule_StringDMA(ctx, k, &len, REDISMODULE_READ);

         // Sadly PUBLISH is only supported with RM_Call at the moment... 
         // Do change what you're publishing here of course
         RedisModule_Call(ctx, "PUBLISH", "cb", MY_PUBSUB_CHANNEL, str, len);

         // Cleanup
         RedisModule_CloseKey(k);
      }
  }
  return REDISMODULE_OK;
}
```

And you can register the handler in your module init call:

```
RedisModule_SubscribeToKeyspaceEvents(ctx, REDISMODULE_NOTIFY_STRING, NotifyCallback);
```